# Convert a nested for loop into recursion in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
          //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
int arr[] = { 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4};
int bee[] = { 6, 8, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int matches[120] = {0};
int length1 = 8;

void find_matches(int *arr, int *bee, int*matches);

void find_matches(int *arr, int *bee, int *matches)
{
    for (i = 0; i<length1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < length1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]==bee[j])
            {
                matches[i] = j;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int z = 0; z<8; z++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", matches[z]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    find_matches(arr, bee, matches);
}
```

The gist of my code is that it is matches every value of `arr[]` to `bee[]` and puts the index of the matches as numbers in the `matches` arrays and prints.

For example the value 3 in `arr[0]` is matched to the value 3 in `bee[5]` so the value of `matches[0]` will be 5.

How can I turn this into a recursive function?

I tried keeping the outer for loop and running the outer with a recursion function call inside but I don't know how to set up the variables and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twofold recursion, over both arrays - see the comments:

```
// recursives
void find_matches(int *arr, int *bee, int *matches, int current_position_in_arr);
void find_matches_in_bee(int *arr, int *bee, int *matches, int current_position_in_arr, int current_position_in_bee);

// wrapper
void find_matches(int *arr, int *bee, int *matches) {
    find_matches(arr, bee, matches, 0);
}

// outer loop : iterate over 'arr'
void find_matches(int *arr, int *bee, int *matches, int current_position_in_arr) {
    // check where arr[current_position_in_arr] is present in bee
    find_matches_in_bee(arr, bee, matches, current_position_in_arr, 0);

    // "next iteration of loop" - we check the next element in arr
    if (current_position_in_arr + 1 < length) {
        find_matches(arr, bee, matches, current_position_in_arr + 1);
    }
}

// inner loop : iterate over 'bee'
void find_matches_in_bee(int *arr, int *bee, int *matches, int current_position_in_arr, int current_position_in_bee) {
    // do your business magic
    if (arr[current_position_in_arr] == bee[current_position_in_bee]) {
       ....
    }

    // "next iteration of loop" - we check the next element in bee
    if (current_position_in_bee + 1 < length) {
        find_matches_in_bee(arr, bee, matches, current_position_in_arr, current_position_in_bee + 1);
    }
}
```

Invoke the same way as before:

```
find_matches(arr, bee, matches);
```

---

The lesson here is that you can replace stuff like:

```
int *array;

for (int i = 0; i < LEN; ++i) {
  f(array[i]);
}
```

with

```
void f(int *array) {
  f_inner(array, 0);
}

void f_inner(int *array, int position) {
  // business logic on array[position]

  // iteration step
  if (position + 1 < LEN) {
    f_inner(array, position + 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
          //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
int arr[] = { 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4};
int bee[] = { 6, 8, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7};
int matches[120] = {0};
int length1 = 8;

void find_matches(int *arr, int *bee, int *matches, int i)
{
    if (i == length1)
        return ;
    for (int j = 0; j < length1; ++j)
        if (arr[i]==bee[j])
            matches[i] = j;
    printf("%d\n", matches[i]);
    find_matches(arr, bee, matches, i + 1);
}

int main()
{
    find_matches(arr, bee, matches, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is clean and clear as presented in nested loops. Why would you want to delibrately convert it to recursion? If you really want, how about

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
          //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
int arr[] = { 3, 6, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 4};
int bee[] = { 6, 8, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int matches[120] = {0};
int length1 = 8;

// iterate over bee
void match(int i, int j)
{
    if (j < 0)
        return;
    if (arr[i] == bee[j]) {
        matches[i] = j;
        return;
    }
    match(i, j - 1);
}

// iterate over arr
void fit(int i)
{
    if (i > 7)
        return;
    match(i, 7);
    fit(i + 1);
}

void find_matches_recursively()
{
    fit(0);
    for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++)
        printf("%d\n", matches[z]);        
}

int main()
{
    find_matches_recursively();
}
```

Output

```
6
5
2
4
5
7
1
3
```

which is the same as in your code.

*Note: You have duplicated values in your `bee[8]` (value 6 in position 0 and position 5). Your iteration loops over all values and records the last match. My recursion searches from the tail and returns immediately when it finds the first match. The effect is the same.*